# Get a specific document without browsing all instances

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm using a ODatabaseDocumentTx instance to handle my documents in DB, and i can't find an equivalent of the function "getVertexByKey" which is usefull to get a specific Vertex with an OrientBaseGraph instance.

I did add an unique index to my class but i don't find how to use it, my only solution from now is to use the "browseClass" function this way :

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(...);

List<ODocument> list = db.browseClass("MyClass");

for (ODocument doc : list) {
 if (doc.field("name").equals("name_i_need")) {
  // and here i can use it
 }
}
```

This is kind of... disgusting !

I'd like a way to do that the way i do with Vertex :

```
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph(...);

Vertex v = graph.getVertexByKey("MyVertexClass.name", "name_i_need");
```

way more beautiful.

I am pretty sure this function exist but i can't find it with orient documentation.
If it doesn't, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create class YourClass
create property YourClass.name string
create index YourClass.name unique

insert into YourClass set name = 'name_you_need'
```

After the above, you can:

```
ODatabaseDocument database = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/DB").open("admin", "admin");

OIndex<?> nameIdx = database.getMetadata().getIndexManager().getIndex("YourClass.name");
OIdentifiable oId = (OIdentifiable) nameIdx.get("name_you_need");
System.out.println(oId.getRecord().toJSON());
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I first tried to directly use ODocument instead of OIdentifiable but it does not seem to work, but i'm fine using oId.getIdentity(). I wouldn't have find this alone, thank you